# How to bind panorama item to screen size width?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, panorama-control

how can I make a panorama item the size of the screen?

like how to access the screen size width in xaml and maybe bind to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Panorama control](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/panorama.shtml) is used to build modern style user interface for Windows Forms applications and is able to display tile elements in a mosaic manner.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've set an explicit width on the Panorama control itself or the panorama item, the appropriate width will be set for you. This width will always be somewhat less than the width of the screen so that the user can see a glimpse of the next panorama item (which provides the usability clue that they can swipe to see additional information).

Can you perhaps explain what you are trying to do in terms of UI? That may let people come up with alternative suggestions for controls that could be a better fit for your scenario than a Panorama control.